# Spring with RabbitMQ example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, amqp

I am so confused about using spring with RabbitMQ.

I did a sample program using RabbitMQ Jars (like given in the RabbitMQ site). I used this code in Spring MVC (for producer), and stand alone java program (for Consumer). Its working fine.

But when I search for AMQP RabbitMQ Spring samples, I get so many variations.

Especially, I don't understand the XML configuration part. In one example, I see XML files with tags

```
  <rabbit:admin/>
  <rabbit:connection-factory/>
```

etc, and in another example, I just see plain `<beans>` for connection factory and no mention of `<rabbit>` related tags in XML. I am a newbie to the messaging stuff and this is confusing to me.

All that I would like to see is a complete Spring MVC or Basic Spring Application using AMQP to send/receive (producer/consumer) message to/from RabbitMQ.

Comment: some sample code here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/sample-apps.html

Comment: This helps. I am looking for complete example.

Comment: While on a similar quest I found this: https://www.candidjava.com/tutorial/spring-boot-rabbitmq-example-using-maven/
But it was not as direct and simple as I had hoped.  Perhaps it will help you or lead you to something more useful for your needs.